# FileStreamResult NOT returning file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I have very simple example to export some data to Excel file, in some reason I see the bytes in the response but no file downloaded why?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> exportRecordsToExcel()
{
    var file = await ServiceRequestBL.ExportFO_SrviceRequestToExcel();
  
    return file;
}    

public async Task<FileStreamResult> ExportFO_SrviceRequestToExcel()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Grid");
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[13] {
        new DataColumn("1"), new DataColumn("2"), new DataColumn("g"), new DataColumn("j"), new DataColumn("k"), new DataColumn("l"), new DataColumn("x"), new DataColumn("m"), new DataColumn("9"), new DataColumn("8"), new DataColumn("7"), new DataColumn("6"), new DataColumn("5")});
    byte[] data = null;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        IFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        dt.RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Binary;
        bf.Serialize(stream, dt);
        data = stream.ToArray();
    }
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    string filename = "Report.xlsx";

    return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "application/ms-excel") { FileDownloadName = filename };
}
```

Comment: You pass empty newly created `memoryStream`  to `FileStreamResult`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a `using` block when using `FileStreamResult`, as this wrapper will take care of disposing the stream when it is no longer needed (it already uses `using` internally).

Simply serialize your data into a stream with `Serialize(stream, ...)` as you have, and pass that stream over to `FileStreamResult`. Let it take of care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an empty `MemoryStream` rather than the one you stored the data in

```cs
public Task<FileStreamResult> ExportFO_SrviceRequestToExcel()
{
    var dt = new DataTable("Grid")
    {
        RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Binary,
        Columns =
        {
            {"1"}, {"2"}, {"g"}, {"j"}, {"k"}, {"l"}, {"x"},
            {"m"}, {"9"}, {"8"}, {"7"}, {"6"}, {"5"}
        },
    };
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(stream, dt);
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    string filename = "Report.xlsx";

    return Task.FromResult(new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "application/ms-excel") { FileDownloadName = filename });
}
```

The stream does not need a `using` because `FileStreamResult` will dispose it, and in any case it's a `MemoryStream` which is backed only by an array.

Also, in this case there is no need for `async` as you are not awaiting anything.

I note that `BinaryFormatter` is deprecated and has security issues. Consider using another serializer if possible.